# Workbox, staleWhileRevalidate called only once on image

Tags: javascript, caching, web-applications, workbox

I'm developing a PWA and I'm trying to use workbox to manage the service-worker and the caching of assets.

In my PWA I have to show all the newer images if the device is online and, if not, the images in the cache.

When I try to implement it I see that the staleWhileRevalidate method on image is called only once in the page for each image, also if I try to refresh multiple times. I need to close the webpage and when I reopen it the image is updated correctly. It's normal that it work in this way?

When I try it with localhost, the staleWhileRevalidate is called every time I reload the page, but when I load the website on a remote server, the app does not work anymore in this way.

`service-worker.js`:

```
importScripts('workbox-sw.prod.v2.0.0.js');
const workboxSW = new WorkboxSW();
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache';
var filesToCache = [
  'imgs/images.png',
   'index.html'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching App Shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});



workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
 /.*\/imgs\/(.*\/)?.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)/,
 ({event}) => {
 console.log("staleWhileRevalidate called);
   return workboxSW.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: CACHE_NAME}).handle({event}).catch((error) => {
     console.log("Error staleWhileRevalidate");
     return error;
   });
 }
);
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title class="title">PWA</title>


 </head>

<body>

<div class="container">
            <img src="imgs/image.png">
</div>

<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Installing (not in localhost)**
[image]

**First Reload (not in localhost)**
[image]

**Second Reload (and more times)**
[image]

Comment: Are you using different domains for your images and for your HTML? Your route, as its written, will only match same-domain requests for images; if you want it to match cross-domain requests, you need to include a regular expression that matches the first part of the remote domain: https://workboxjs.org/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing.RegExpRoute.html#main Using the dev bundle, `workbox-sw.dev.v2.0.0.js` bundle should give you better error messages.

Comment: The images and the HTML are all in a folder in a my remote server. 
The index.html is in a path like    www.mywebsite.com/test/index.html
The images are in a path like www.mywebsite.com/test/imgs/image.png

I tried to use the dev bundle but the only thing that changes is that in the console I see the below warning:
 "[Warn] This appears to be a production server. Please switch to the smaller, optimized production build of Workbox."

Comment: Possibly stupid idea, if you go to Application Tab > Service Workers, under the service worker for your site, is there a link saying 'inspect' when you stop seeing the messages?

Comment: I have just uploaded all files on my test server, the link is this https://slidepro.it/test/  
Sorry but I don't understand where I should to see the link 'inspect', under my service worker I see only the date of reception (For example 'Received 30/9/2017, 15:00:00'), the status and the clients